# Is there a way to prevent variables from changing their type in Python?

Tags: python, variables, dynamic-typing, duck-typing

It is useful to have the interpreter derive the type of a variable automatically. This on its own is similar to the `auto` keyword in C++11. However, in Python variables can change their type after being declared for the first time. This potentially can cause a lot of errors. I haven't seen any reasonable use case for this, besides changing from or to `None`.

For performance reasons, PyPy claims to be written in what they call [RPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyPy#RPython), which goes into this direction. However, it seems like there is neither a standard for this nor a way to make the interpreter complain about type changing.

Is there a way to prevent variables from changing their type in Python?

Comment: No - that's the whole point of dynamic typing.

Comment: Do you want a yes/no answer or are you open to being sold on why this isn't a terrible thing(tm)?

Comment: There is no way to prevent this. However, there also isn't a generally accepted reason why! Myself, I have great trouble understanding why people would want the type of a variable to vary. But many, many others have trouble seeing why some would NOT want it to vary, e.g. see here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134486

Comment: @KilianFoth [“All that specificity \[of interfaces/classes/types\] kills your reuse!”](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/199461/31260)

Comment: Use something like [MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/) or a statically typed language (like e.g. Go).

Comment: @danjar One surprising thing I like about the Rust language is that variables can change type *if* you explicitly ask them to, but don't otherwise. This often shows up when unwrapping a type, e.g. `let s: Option<String> = ...; if s.is_none() { return; } let s: String = s.unwrap(); let s: &str = s.as_slice()` (also the type declarations are optional of unambiguous, except in function arguments)

Comment: @delnan Yes, I'm open to an answer why this might actually be an advantage. I just haven't seen it this way yet.

Comment: @Doval I know. What I want is a version of Python with dynamic typing disabled. Besides that, I see a lot of strong points in Python.

Comment: @danijar Dynamic typing isn't something you can "disable" (unless you want undefined behavior.) To begin with, dynamic languages are static languages with a single type, so you're really talking about *adding* to the language, not turning off parts of it. Enforcing static typing in *all* Python code would break existing code, too, so you'd have to accept holes in your type checking. You should probably look for statically typed languages with Python's strong points. I'm guessing you like the uncluttered syntax and conciseness; you might want to look into functional languages like OCaml or F#.

Comment: It is not variables, it is values, which have some type. By extension, a variable which is bound only to values of a given type is said to have that type.

Answer (score 3):

A Python variable is not like a C variable, which is to say it is not a box with data inside it.  A Python variable is more like a sticky note that has been stuck on a box with data inside it.

The type of the box's data *rarely* changes, but the sticky note can be passed from box to box to box.

So, the type isn't really changing.

Having said that, there are ways to limit this:  Use a class with custom descriptors to check and enforce what new value is trying to be assigned to your sticky-note variable name, and use a custom metaclass to prevent the class variable sticky note from being reassigned to something else.

I beleive [Enthought Traits](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/) have this ability.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Use a type checker and [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) type hints.